# Percentile in MySQL grouped by date

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have a database table which basically has columns `date Date, int UserId, double Value`.

I'd like to be able to do a query giving me the 10% and 90% percentiles for Value per date over all Users, so something like `SELECT Date, Pct10(Value), Pct90(Value) from Table group by Date`.

I am aware of different ways to calculate percentiles in MySQL using `Count(*)` and `LIMIT` and counting rows, however, I don't see how to apply this iteratively for every date value within one statement.

Example data:

```
Date       | UserId  | Value
2013-01-01 |      0  |     1
2013-01-01 |      1  |     1
2013-01-01 |      2  |     1
2013-01-01 |      3  |     1
2013-01-01 |      4  |     2
2013-01-01 |      5  |     2
2013-01-01 |      6  |     2
2013-01-01 |      7  |     2
2013-01-01 |      8  |     2
2013-01-01 |      9  |     2
2013-01-01 |     10  |     9
2013-01-02 |      1  |     1
2013-01-02 |      9  |     1
```

Excpected result would be

```
Date       | Pct10  | Pct90
2013-01-01 |     1  |     2
2013-01-02 |     1  |     1
```

Comment: how do you calculate the percentuals?

Comment: That's my question. There is no Pctxx() function in MySQL. 90% percentile would be counting all matching rows of that date and taking the value of the row at position 0.9 * count (the rows being sorted by value).

Comment: What I mean is from where you get the 10% or the 90%! Sorry if I misunderstand you. But I did'nt get "taking the value of the row at position 0.9". You have to have a value to calculate, so, you want to sum all values then take the 10% or the 90% from it or what? Sorry again if I don't undestand you... My english is not so good

Comment: Jorge, see here for an explanation of Percentile: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile

Comment: I undestanded it already, you wanna the row corresponding to 10% or 90% of the number of rows on the query grouped by date

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about getting the percentiles.  I am using a subquery based on [select nth percentile from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065855/select-nth-percentile-from-mysql?rq=1) below, but I'm not quite sure I have modified it correctly.  The point of my answer is in the combining of the subqueries.

The following query would be slow and get exponentially slower as the table increases in size, but it should do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT p10.Date, Pct10, Pct90
FROM (
    SELECT Date, count(Value) AS Pct10
    FROM mydata 
    GROUP BY Date, Value
    ORDER BY ABS(0.1-(count(Value)/(select count(*) from mydata)))
    LIMIT 1) AS p10
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Date, count(Value) AS Pct9
    FROM mydata 
    GROUP BY Date, Value
    ORDER BY ABS(0.9-(count(Value)/(select count(*) from mydata)))
    LIMIT 1) AS p90 ON p10.Date = p90.Date
GROUP BY p1.Date
```

Here is my second idea.  If it works, it would be faster and more efficient than the first one I listed, but still be pretty slow for larger tables.

```
SELECT p10.Date, count(Value) AS Pct10, Pct90
FROM mydata p10
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Date, count(Value) AS Pct90
    FROM mydata 
    GROUP BY Date, Value
    ORDER BY ABS(0.9-(count(Value)/(select count(*) from mydata)))
    LIMIT 1) AS p90 ON p10.Date = p90.Date
GROUP BY Date, Value
ORDER BY ABS(0.1-(count(Value)/(select count(*) from mydata)))
LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT**

OK, brainstorming time.  Given that this is a subquery for a percentile for one date (I am not even sure this is how it works):

```
    SELECT Date, count(Value) AS Pct90
    FROM mydata 
    WHERE Date = ?
    GROUP BY Value
    ORDER BY ABS(0.9-(count(Value)/(select count(*) from mydata WHERE Date = ?)))
    LIMIT 1
```

Then let's try to fix the ORDER BY:

```
   SELECT Date, count(Value) as Pct90
   FROM mydata
   INNER JOIN (SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS DateTotal FROM mydata GROUP BY Date) AS d 
       ON d.Date = mydata.Date
   GROUP BY Date, Value
   ORDER BY (ABS(0.9-(COUNT(Value)/d.DateTotal)))
   LIMIT 1
```

If you use this pattern in my previous examples, maybe it will work.

**EDIT 2**

So, here we go again because we can't use LIMIT 1 (which I should have realized before).  I actually tested the following on my own database (hopefully, I changed all the field and table names back how they should be!) and it seems to work.  You'll have to do this again for p10 and combine the two.

```
--- removed due to typos ---
```

**EDIT 3**

I found some errors in Edit 2, so I deleted it.  Here is the whole percentage query.  This query works on my database (using different fields and tables), as far as I can tell.

```
SELECT n.Date, n.Pct AS Pct10, n.Value AS Pct10Value, q.Pct AS Pct90, q.Value AS Pct90Value FROM (
    SELECT p.Date, p.Pct, p.Value, m.Selector FROM (
        SELECT mydata.Date, Value, COUNT(Value) as Pct, (ABS(0.1-(COUNT(Value)/d.DateTotal))) AS Abs10
        FROM mydata
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS DateTotal FROM mydata GROUP BY Date) AS d 
            ON d.Date = mydata.Date
        GROUP BY Date, Value
        ) p
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Date, MIN(Abs10) AS Selector FROM (
            SELECT mydata.Date, Value, COUNT(Value) as Pct, (ABS(0.1-(COUNT(Value)/d.DateTotal))) AS Abs10
            FROM mydata
            INNER JOIN (SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS DateTotal FROM mydata GROUP BY Date) AS d 
            ON d.Date = mydata.Date
            GROUP BY Date, Value
        ) x GROUP BY Date
    ) AS m ON m.Selector = p.Abs10
    GROUP BY p.Date) n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.Date, p.Pct, p.Value, m.Selector FROM (
        SELECT mydata.Date, Value, COUNT(Value) as Pct, (ABS(0.9-(COUNT(Value)/d.DateTotal))) AS Abs90
        FROM mydata
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS DateTotal FROM mydata GROUP BY Date) AS d 
            ON d.Date = mydata.Date
        GROUP BY Date, Value
        ) p
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Date, MIN(Abs90) AS Selector FROM (
            SELECT mydata.Date, Value, COUNT(Value) as Pct, (ABS(0.9-(COUNT(Value)/d.DateTotal))) AS Abs90
            FROM mydata
            INNER JOIN (SELECT Date, COUNT(*) AS DateTotal FROM mydata GROUP BY Date) AS d 
                ON d.Date = mydata.Date
            GROUP BY Date, Value
        ) x GROUP BY Date
    ) AS m ON m.Selector = p.Abs90
    GROUP BY p.Date) q ON q.Date = n.Date
```

Comment: I'd say this can't be correct, as you have `select count(*) from mydata` without any date restriction, however every date would have another count.

Comment: @stacktracer Yeah, I was pretty sure I hadn't modified that other answer correctly.  Let me think a bit longer on it.

Comment: Does not seem to work: Because of the Limit 1 the queries only return one row, and not one row per date.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a version that seemed to work when I tested it on my own database.

Comment: Thanks for you efforts. Running this gives me:

`Date       Pct10     Pct10Value Pct90     Pct90Value` 
`2013-10-11     8 0.679958057956     8 0.679958057956` 
`2013-10-12     8 0.679958057956     8 0.679958057956` 
`2013-10-13     9 0.688678662728     9 0.688678662728` 

So something is not working, as the 90 and 10% percentiles actually are different looking at the data.

Comment: That's strange.  My database gave me very different values for Pct10 and Pct90, except for the dates with too little data (only two values on one day).  I think you might have a typo or there might be something odd about your data. Try running just one of the selects joined as "p" and seeing the spread of Pct and Abs90/Abs10. The row that gets selected should be the one with the lowest Abs90/Abs10.

Comment: I used this as a test and it did not work: `create table mydata (id int auto_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, value double, date date);` `insert into mydata (value, date) values (rand(), '2013-10-28'), (rand(), '2013-10-27');` (repeat this 10 times to that both dates have at least 10 values). Then execute your query. Pct10 and Pct90 were 1 for both days and the Values the same as previously seen.

Comment: The way it works is, this is figuring the percentile of "how many times Value X appears."  If you have values A-Z, and each of them appears once, then Pct10 will likely be the same as Pct90, because all of the values are tied for Pct10 and Pct90, so the one that comes out gets chosen out of the same tie twice, based on how the database naturally orders things.  If X appears twice and all the other letters A-Z appear once, then X will be Pct90 but the rest will be tied for Pct10 and one of the things in that tie will come out the same as I described before.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is, if A and B occur the same number of times, then they will have the same Abs90.  That means they will both be selected by MIN(Abs90) = Abs90 in the subquery x.  Because I did not specify an order for any of the subqueries, the database naturally picks the first one it comes to, which may or may not be A.  And this same tie can happen again in Abs10 = MIN(Abs10) because A and B still have an equal number of values.

Comment: The correct way to test my query is to create a situation where you know for sure what values should be Pct10 and what ones should be Pct90.  So, do your create table again, but instead of using rand(), insert ten of A, five of B, and one of C for each date.  The query should then return Pct10 = C and Pct90 = A for each date.  Build it on sqlfiddle so we can take a look. I am on vacation now so I don't have access to my previous tests.

Comment: As the values are doulbe, it is unlikely that the same value would appear multiple times. Your solution seems not to work if all values are distinct.

Comment: Mathematically, percentile is meaningless when all the values being compared are the same. If you gave a test to 50 kids and they all scored exactly 70%, then how do you tell which of those kids is in the 90th percentile? You can't, because they are all at the 50th percentile. The reason the same values appear for 10th and 90th percentiles is that all the values come out to be 10th and 90th percentile at the same time. Mysql returns the first one it comes to, twice.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql version 5.x, use this method bellow to caculate percentile for one day:

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  t.*
           ,@row_num := @row_num + 1 AS row_num
    FROM mydata t,
    (
        SELECT  @row_num := 0
    ) counter
    WHERE Date BETWEEN "2022-07-15" AND "2022-07-16"
    ORDER BY total_time 
) temp
WHERE temp.row_num = ROUND (.90 * @row_num);
```

So, the `@row_num` is a `Selector`. For group percetile, we get each group's selector just like this:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS day
        ,ROUND (0.10 * Count(1)) + min(idx) - 1 as p10_idx
        ,ROUND (0.90 * Count(1)) + min(idx) - 1 as p90_idx
FROM
(
    SELECT  dt
            ,@selector_idx := @selector_idx +1 AS idx
    FROM mydata,
    (
        SELECT  @selector_idx := 0
    ) C
) T
group by day
order by day
```

Then, add row index in Data table order by Value. and left join the Selector to filter the p10/p90 row.

```
SELECT  D.day
       ,CASE WHEN D.idx = Selector.p10_idx THEN D.Value END as p10
       ,CASE WHEN D.idx = Selector.p90_idx THEN D.Value END as p90
FROM
(
    SELECT  id, dt, DATE_FORMAT(dt,"%Y-%m-%d") AS day
           ,Value
           ,@data_idx := @data_idx +1          AS idx
    FROM mydata,
    (
        SELECT  @data_idx := 0
    ) C
    ORDER BY day, Value 
) D
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(dt,"%Y-%m-%d") AS day
           ,ROUND (0.10 * Count(1)) + min(idx) - 1 as p10_idx
           ,ROUND (0.90 * Count(1)) + min(idx) - 1 as p90_idx
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  dt
               ,@selector_idx := @selector_idx +1 AS idx
        FROM mydata,
        (
            SELECT  @selector_idx := 0
        ) C
    ) T
    group by day
    order by day
) AS Selector
ON D.day = Selector.day
WHERE D.idx = Selector.p90_idx or D.idx = Selector.p10_idx;
GROUP BY D.day
```